# C# creating xml file from a class object

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My company has 17 payment types. When a new user is on-boarded all these 17 types should be assigned by default and a xml should be generated as below

XML representation of data:

```
<User>
    <UserId>nnn</UserId>
    <UserName>cccc</UserName>
    <PaymentTypes>
        <Payment>
          <PaymentType>Payment_Type1</PaymentType>
          <PaymentTypeID>1</PaymentTypeID>
          <Setting>true</Setting>
        </Payment>
        <Payment>
          <PaymentType>Payment_Type2</PaymentType>
          <PaymentTypeID>2</PaymentTypeID>
          <Setting>true</Setting>
        </Payment>
        .
        .
        .
        <Payment>
          <PaymentType>Payment_Type17</PaymentType>
          <PaymentTypeID>17</PaymentTypeID>
          <Setting>true</Setting>
        </Payment>
    </PaymentTypes>
</User>
```

---

I have created a class which holds all the xml elements as data members and array type for this calls

```
public partial class PaymentTypes {
    
    private string paymentTypeField;
    
    private byte paymentTypeIDField;
    
    private bool settingField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string PaymentType {
        get {
            return this.paymentTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.paymentTypeField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public byte PaymentTypeID {
        get {
            return this.paymentTypeIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.paymentTypeIDField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public bool Setting {
        get {
            return this.settingField;
        }
        set {
            this.settingField = value;
        }
    }
}

private PaymentTypes[] paymentTypesField;
    
public PaymentTypes[] PaymentTypes {
    get {
        return this.paymentTypesField;
    }
    set {
        this.paymentTypesField = value;
    }
}
```

---

I am able to instantiate class and assign values..

```
PaymentTypes pt = new PaymentTypes();
pt.PaymentType = "Payment_Type1";
pt.PaymentTypeID = 1;
pt.Setting = true;

PaymentTypes pt1 = new PaymentTypes();
pt1.PaymentType = "Payment_Type2";
pt1.PaymentTypeID = 2;
pt1.Setting = true;

.
.
.

PaymentTypes pt16 = new PaymentTypes();
pt16.PaymentType = "Payment_Type17";
pt16.PaymentTypeID = 17;
pt16.Setting = true;

// Insert payment types into the array.
PaymentTypes[] paymentTypes = { pt, pt1,.....,pt16 };

//assign all 17 payment types to user object
user.PaymentTypes = paymentTypes;
```

by using xml serializer, I am able to generate the output xml as above.

---

Drawback of the above code: it is not efficient.

1. I have created an instance of `PaymentTypes` class 17 times, with different values
2. 17 variables to hold different payment types
3. more lines of code
4. more time for execution
5. more memory consumption

**Question**: is there any better way to define all 17 payment types and assign to user object with minimal line of code or easy way or quick way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a static Create() method that creates an instance for the class PaymentTypes and you can rewrite the properties in the contracted form like below.

```
public partial class PaymentTypes {

    public static Create(byte paymentTypeID, string paymentType, bool setting)
    {
        return new PaymentTypes 
        {
            PaymentTypeID = paymentTypeID,
            PaymentType = paymentType,
            Setting = setting
        };
    }    

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte PaymentTypeID { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool Setting { get; set; }
}
```

And  then you can assign  payment types to the user in this way:

```
//assign all 17 payment types to user object
user.PaymentTypes = new PaymentTypes[] 
{
    PaymentTypes.Create(1, "Payment_Type1", true),
    PaymentTypes.Create(2, "Payment_Type2", false),
    ....
    PaymentTypes.Create(17, "Payment_Type17", true)
};
```

Or without the Create() static method:

```
//assign all 17 payment types to user object
user.PaymentTypes = new PaymentTypes[] 
{
    new PaymentTypes{ PaymentTypeID = 1, PaymentType = "PaymentType_1", Setting = true },
    new PaymentTypes{ PaymentTypeID = 2, PaymentType = "PaymentType_2", Setting = false },
    ....
    new PaymentTypes{ PaymentTypeID = 17, PaymentType = "PaymentType_17", Setting = true }
};
```

For the memory consumption I don't see any issue in your code because effectively you need to allocate 17 instances of the class PaymentType and since the classes are reference types they are not allocated in the stack memory.